# Cryptographic hash of the entire Ethereum database

Tags: blockchain, hash, cryptography

I need a cryptographic hash of the entire Ethereum database (of the information in all blocks up to a certain block number). Is there a service that calculates this hash?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by that.

The block hash is the hash of ordered blocks and their ordered transactions up to the block height.

If you want to easily prove something outside what is already provided then you might have to consume the chain and organize appropriately.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain clearly what is "the hash of ordered blocks and their ordered transactions up to the block height". Do you mean that the block hash is the hash of the data containing all the information in each block up to the block height?

Comment: The block hash is the hash of all of the information in the block _and_ the previous block hash. Including the hash of the previous block ensures that each block is a successor to the previous block. This is the "chain" aspect of blockchain. A well-ordered set of blocks that are each a well-ordered set of transactions is a well-ordered set of transactions from inception to the latest-known block.